# В России, но на Руси - почему?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как-то тут уже обсуждался вопрос предлогов "а" и "на". Пришли к выводу, что "на" употребляется в отношении островов чаще всего. Ну и часто говорят "на Украине". Но почему же тогда "на Руси", но при этом "в России"?
Спасибо

Comment: К слову, "на Украине" не просто часто говорят. Это литературная норма русского языка.

Comment: Совершенно верно! И зачем было искажать?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Русь представляется  как территории поселения русского народа, поэтому говорят "на Руси" (на территории Руси).

Россия - это уже государство, поэтому говорят "в России" (в государстве).

ИЗ ИСТОРИИ НАЗВАНИЙ

Россия, получив свое название в лучшем случае в ХVІІІ веке. И в XV, и в XVI, и даже в XVIII столетии в летописях географы четко различают Московию и Русь. В самой Московии термины "Росия", "Россия" для обозначения страны впервые и очень ограниченно начали употреблять только в XVI веке, с тех пор, как в Москве появляется идея "Третьего Рима".

Московия переименовалась по царской команде 1713 и 1721 годов. Слово "русский" закрепилось даже позже – только в конце XVIII века, когда царица Екатерина II "высочайшим повелением" окончательно приказала московскому народу называться "русскими" и запретила ему употреблять название "московитяне".
http://forum-pmr.net/showthread.php?t=110317

Comment: Россия  стоит  в  титуле  царя  Фёдора  Иоанновича  ( конец  16-го века ). Затем,  в  титуле  Бориса  Годунова,  снова  Русь.  Но,  начиная  с  Лжедмитрия  и  до  последних  Романовых  -  Россия.  Как  основное  наименование  государства.

Comment: ИЗ ИСТОРИИ НАЗВАНИЙ 
Ну, зачем повторять эту свидомую чушь...

Comment: "Московия" — это понятие польское, уж точно само Московское княжество так себя не величало.

Comment: Жихарка! Поясните, пожалуйста, слово "свидомый"

Comment: @Ларf, "свидомый" - это от украинкого «національна свідомість» — «национальная сознательность». Здесь употреблено в значении, "сочинённое проукраинцами".

Не знаю кем сочинен, текст от Софии (судя по ссылке действительно "свидомым"), но даже в представленном в ответе отрывке, не углубляясь в подробности нашёл 1 ложный факт, пара правдивых лишь с точки зрения Польши и ещё несколько, в которых сильно сомневаюсь, но я это не проверял и что-то утверждать не берусь.

@София, минус мой, за популяризацию ложных сведений. Будьте аккуратнее, давая историческую справку, на не известную вам тему.

Comment: Согласен  с  МаркИзом.

Comment: Да, исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: Желательно: на неизвестную Вам тему.  Наличие зависимых слов у прилагательных не приводит к раздельному написанию НЕ, в отличие от причастий.

Comment: Какие "московитяне", что вы бредите София. Какой указ Екатерины запрещающий называться? Дата издания указа и текст со ссылкой на достоверный источник? А не ссылка на форум как источник, где такие же свидомые пишут... Типичный украинский бред. У вас вся наука там на таком уровне?

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что Русь как государство восприниматься стала только в веке XVIII и то лишь в исторических работах, до этого Русь - это место проживания восточных славян (! не беру в расчет времена первых князей,  из-за неясной этимологии). Русский (слово встречают с XII в.), соответственно - это восточный славянин. Вплоть до ХХ века русский было примерно равно современному россиянин, но затем осталось лишь за самым многочисленным восточнославянским народом - великоросами.

Слово "Россия" же уже изначально было обозначением именно государства, с определенными границами. В нынешнем виде впервые зафиксировано в 1517-м году.

С местностью в русском языке чаще используется предлог "на", а с государствами "в"

Answer (score 0):

Въ ПВЛ (Повѣсть врємѧнныхъ лѣтъ) пишется «въ Руси», «въ Русь». Кто придумал «на Руси»— не знаю, «на»— это где-то сбоку Руси. То же по Украинѣ. Мнемоническое правило: «на»— наружи, «въ»— внутри.
Пушкинъ-то неграмотной мужикъ былъ, въ поэмѣ «Полтава», въ сноскахъ и предисловіи къ ней писалъ «въ Украйну». Иронія))) [Сочинения А. С. Пушкина. 3-е изд., испр. и доп., под ред. П. А. Ефремова. СПб., 1880—1881.] http://www.lib.pushkinskijdom.ru/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=i2Ln5zNyG98%3D&tabid=10326
“Ошибка шведскаго короля вошла въ пословицу. Его упрекаютъ въ неосторожности, находятъ его походъ въ Украину безразсуднымъ.” 
“Езуитъ Заленскій, княгиня Дудьская и какой-то болгарскій apxiепископъ, изгнанный изъ своего отечества, были главными агентами Мазепиной измѣны. Послѣдній въ видѣ нищаго ходилъ изъ Польши въ Украйну и обратно”.
“Незапно Карлъ поворотилъ 
И перенесъ войну въ Украину.”
“Старикъ Палѣй изъ мрака ссылки
Въ Украйну ѣдетъ въ царскій станъ”.